# Text wrapped around a 3D cylinder effect using CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible, using some type of CSS3 black magic, to mimic the the iOS7 datepicker effect of wrapping text around a 3D cylinder (see screenshot below), given a static unordered list with a known height?

[image: ios7 datepicker]

Comment: [3D Transforms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: @bjb568 yeah, I figured transforms would be my best bet, however even after looking through the docs and experimenting I've been unable to come up with a combination of skews/scales/rotates ect that could accurately replicate this effect. Could you provide a specific example that uses transforms to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotateX('+(i-e.length/2)*20+'deg) translateZ(40px)';
}
```

Rotate and translate. Keep them all `absolute`. http://jsfiddle.net/CAbkL/

If they're static and you know beforehand how many there are, you can use plain CSS:

```
#d1 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-75deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d2 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-60deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d3 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-45deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d4 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d5 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-15deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d7 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d8 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d9 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d10 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(60deg) translateZ(40px) }
#d11 { -webkit-transform: rotateX(75deg) translateZ(40px) }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CAbkL/1/

Oh, and [-vendor-prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d).

Comment: perfect, thank you! In case anyone else stumbles upon this, here is a prettied-up version of @bjb568's solution, styled like the iOS7 picker: http://codepen.io/billdami/pen/bCIxs

Comment: Also, I was able to omit the absolute positioning and `translateZ()`'s  and just added some negative margins to the first and last element to take care of the distorted spacing. Not sure if there's any disadvantage to doing that instead tho.

Comment: @Bill Well, you manually space anything with margins… Anyway, you should use `em` in this case to make it work with font-size adjusted browsers.